# alignment not working between image and text inside a div

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to align an image next to a title but I am not able to to do that. I have added color background just to see the position of each element.

below is the code :

```
            <Col className="create-tile">
                <div className="create-style-title">
                    <img
                        src= { TeachIcon }
                        className= "create-icon"
                        alt="TeachIcon"
                    />    
                    <h2>{TextContents.BeATeacher}</h2>
                </div>
                <p>{TextContents.BeATeacherDesc}</p>
                <div className="create-button">
                <BlueButton textSize="13" link_href="/createaclass" text={TextContents.BeATeacherBtn} />
                </div>
            </Col>;
```

and the css :

```
.create-container {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 5rem; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40%;
}

.create-container h2 {
    text-align: center;
    height: 51px;
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: red;
}

.create-section {
    width:100%;
}

.create-icon {
    width:47px;
    height:47px ;
}

.create-style-title {
    background-color: blue;
}

.create-tile {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 12px;
    top: 80px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}


.create-tile h2 {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 0.7;
    color: #333333;
    letter-spacing: -0.6px;

}

.create-tile p {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #616161;
    width: 280px;
    height: 85px; 
}

.create-button {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

However it looks like this :

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Any idea ? I tried proposal that I had in the past from stackoverflow but it still not working.
Do not worry about the blue/red bkg, it's really just as support for placing element

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox in create-style-title class like this

```
.create-style-title {
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; //This is for vertical align
}
```

And it should be in the same line

Answer (score 0):

Put your image in **h2** title tag and update below css

```
.create-container {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 5rem; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40%;
}

.create-container h2 {
    text-align: center;
    height: 51px;
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: red;
}

.create-section {
    width:100%;
}

.create-icon {float:left;
    width:47px;
    height:47px;margin-right:20px
}
 
.create-tile {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 12px;
    top: 80px;
    text-align: left; line-height:47px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}


.create-tile h2 {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px; 
    color: #333333;
    letter-spacing: -0.6px;

}

.create-tile p {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #616161;
    width: 280px;
    height: 85px; 
}

.create-button {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```css
.create-container {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 5rem; 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40%;
}

.create-container h2 {
    text-align: center;
    height: 51px;
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 50px;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: red;
}

.create-section {
    width:100%;
}

.create-icon {float:left;
    width:47px;
    height:47px;margin-right:20px
}
 
.create-tile {
    display: inline-block;
    left: 12px;
    top: 80px;
    text-align: left; line-height:47px;
    width: 280px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}


.create-tile h2 {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px; 
    color: #333333;
    letter-spacing: -0.6px;

}

.create-tile p {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    color: #616161;
    width: 280px;
    height: 85px; 
}

.create-button {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="create-tile">
                <div class="create-style-title">
                
                    <h2>       <img
                        src= "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/929/929422.svg"
                        class= "create-icon"
                        alt="TeachIcon"
                    />  Be A Techer</h2>
                </div>
                <p>I am trying to align an image next to a title but I am not able to to do that. I have added color background just to see the position of each element.</p>
                <div class="create-button">
                <BlueButton textSize="13" link_href="/createaclass" text={TextContents.BeATeacherBtn} />
                </div>
            </div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this instead.

Add this CSS to element.

```css
display: flex;
align-items: center; //vertical align
justfy-content: center; //horizontal align
```